# How to find first five terms of sequence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I'm new to recursion so please bear with me. I have to find the first five terms of a sequence with initial conditions $u_1 = 1$ and $u_2 = 5$, and, for $n \geq 3$, $$u_n = 5u_{n−1} − 6u_{n−2}.$$

I believe that $u_3 =  19$, if I'm correct, but after that I'm stuck. Could someone please help me figure the next two terms and the closed formula for this sequence.

Comment: How did you find 19? What's troubling you finding $u_4$?

Comment: @user88595 I used 5^2 -6 to get 19.

Comment: The key is to notice that it says "for $n\geq 3$ ...", which is a lazy way to say that for **every** $n\geq3$ ... Computing the next terms consists in particularizing this statement for specific values of $n$. Take $n=3$, since we need $a_3$. The equation becomes $a_3=5a_{3-1}-6a_{3-2}$, by replacing $n$ by $3$, i.e. $a_3=5a_2-6a_1$. Since we have the values of $a_2$ and $a_1$ we get the value of $a_3$. Put now $n=4$ in the equation, and so on.

Comment: @ABC Thank you I think I get it now. One more thing, how would get the closed formula?

Comment: @Juan247 : Getting a closed formula is much more complicated and not always possible depending on the recursion you have.

Comment: There are many methods for that. One short answer could be that the solution is going to be $a_n=Cr_1^n+Dr_2^n$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the solutions of $r_1^n=5r_1^{n-1}-6r_1^{n-2}$ and $r_1^n=5r_1^{n-1}-6r_1^{n-2}$, for all $n$ and $C$ and $D$ can be found imposing the initial conditions $a_1=1$, $a_2=5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence is given by:

$$u_n = 5 u_{n-1} - 6 u_{n-2}$$

- $u_1 = 1$
- $u_2 = 5$
- $u_3 = 5 u_2 - 6u_1 = 5 \times 5 - 6 \times 1 = 19$
- $u_4 = 5 u_3 - 6 u_2 = 5 \times 19 - 6 \times 5 = 65$
- $u_5 = 5 u_4 - 6 u_3 = 5 \times 65 - 6 \times 19 = 211$
- $\ldots$

Comment: Thank you so much. Even though I came up with 19, I kind of got the answer the wrong way.

Comment: Ok will do. I just have one more question. How would I get this closed formula of this?

Comment: He told us to use pattern guessing to get it. We haven't touched on Geometric series yet.

Comment: Try: http://oeis.org/A001047 (for example: $3^n - 2^n$, for $n = 1, ...$)

Comment: I'm baaack! And looks like I missed your abundant answering! (Math on the brain?)

Comment: Disheartening, indeed, the hitters-and-runners!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that $u_3=5u_2-6u_1=5\cdot 5-6\cdot 1=19$. Now $u_4=5u_3-6u_2$ and you know the terms on the right. Keep going. A spreadsheet with copy down makes this easy.

Comment: Ok thanks I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in thinking that $u_3 = 19$. In a similar fashion, $u_4 = 5\cdot 19 -6\cdot 5 = 95$ and $u_5 = 5\cdot 65 - 6\cdot 19 = 211$.

To find the general solution, we rewrite the recurrence as $u_n - 5u_{n-1} +6u_{n-2} = 0$. This has auxiliary quadratic equation $x^2-5x+6 = (x-2)(x-3)$, so the recurrence is satisfied by something of the form $A2^n + B3^n$. Using your initial conditions, you can solve for $A$ and $B$.

If you've not seen methods like this (they're similar to solving ODEs), see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#General_methods).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the general term by using generating functions. Define $U(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} u_n z^n$. Write your recurrence as:
$$
u_{n + 2} = 5 u_{n + 1} - 6 u_n \qquad u_0 = 0, u_1 = 1
$$
(it is convenient to start the sum at $n = 0$; the value of $u_0$ comes from running the recurrence backwards).

Multiply the recurrence by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$. Recognize:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} u_{n + 1} z^n &= \frac{U(z) - u_0}{z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} u_{n + 2} z^n &= \frac{U(z) - u_0 - u_1 z}{z^2}
\end{align}
and you get:
$$
\frac{U(z) - z}{z^2} = 5 \frac{U(z)}{z} - 6 U(z)
$$
Solving for $U(z)$ and splitting in partial fractions gives:
$$
U(z) = \frac{1}{1 - 3 z} - \frac{1}{1 - 2 z}
$$
This is just two geometric series:
$$
u_n = 3^n - 2^n
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, but we have made it to geometric series yet. How would I get this by pattern guessing?

Comment: @Juan247, guessing depends on luck (and knowing lots and lots of sequences). Sometimes it helps *not* to compute values, but leave them expressed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a closed form:

The OP's equation is a linear homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients.

A technique for solving relations of the form $u_n + Au_{n-1} + Bu_{n-2} = 0$ is to assume $u(n) \propto k^n$ for some value(s) of $k \ne 0$ which we are going to find.

Substituting our guess into the recurrence relation,
$$
k^n + Ak^{n-1} + Bk^{n-2} = 0 \;\forall n \ge 3
$$
Dividing through by $k^{n-2}$ (which is non-zero because $k$ is non-zero by assumption), we get the characteristic polynomial of the recurrence relation:
$$
k^2 + Ak + B = 0
$$

Solving this will give [different solutions](http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2008-09/S/1019/Website_files/21-linear-recurrences.pdf) for $u(n)$ depending on the roots of this quadratic.

Going back to the OP's question: $A=-5$ and $B=6$, so $k^2 - 5k + 6 = (k-2)(k-3) = 0$, so $k=$ 2 or 3.

Thus, the general solution to the OP's original equation is:
$$
u(n) = \alpha2^n + \beta3^n
$$
for some constants $\alpha, \beta$. Substituting in the given initial conditions,

$$
1 = 2\alpha + 3\beta, \; \; 5 = 4\alpha + 9\beta
$$
giving $\alpha = -1$, $\beta = 1$, and so
$$
u(n) = 3^n - 2^n
$$

So as expected, $u(3) = 27-8=19$, and so on.